# TFS: Manipulate security settings permission

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I work with VS2010 and TFS2010. In our team we have some custom Checkin Policies and now I want to give some users (Contributors) the right to add/edit this policies.

I searched in "Team Project Settings-> Security.." but i didn't found a permission like "Manipulate security settings".

Knows somebody where i can grant this permission?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I really really don't think it's a good idea to give Contributors permissions to modify check-in policy (assuming it's possible to do so).  Granting them whatever permission grants updating check-in policy will probably allow them to make other changes you wouldn't want them to do.  This is effectively elevating *all* the Contributors to pseudo Project Administrators.

Check-in policies are good and custom ones are interesting but it is still up to the Project Administrator to enable/disable/configure those policies.  If "some users" need to be able to do this then perhaps it is more appropriate to put those individuals into the Project Administrators group and leave the rest of the Contributors with their more limited set of permissions.